# XML with multiple DOCTYPE declarations

Tags: python, xml, parsing, formatting, doctype

Hello I have a rather large XML file 10-15gb. It contains multiple root Doctype tags, my guess is whoever made it just concatenated a bunch of separate files together. This is definitely not best practice but sometimes it is all you have to work with. I am wondering if anyone has a solution for parsing the file or separating the files into each individual DocType.

So far I have tried wrapping the entire file in one single root tag but this did not work. I am working in Python.

Any solution or input would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pmc-articleset PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD ARTICLE SET 2.0//EN" "https://dtd.nlm.nih.gov/ncbi/pmc/articleset/nlm-articleset-2.0.dtd">

<pmc-articleset><article xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" article-type="research-article">
  <?properties open_access?>
  <front>
    <p>
    Apple
    </p>
  </front>
</article>
</pmc-articleset>
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pmc-articleset PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD ARTICLE SET 2.0//EN" "https://dtd.nlm.nih.gov/ncbi/pmc/articleset/nlm-articleset-2.0.dtd">
<pmc-articleset><article xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" article-type="research-article">
  <?properties open_access?>
  <front>
    <p>
    Banana
    </p>
  </front>
</article>
</pmc-articleset>
```

Comment: If it has multiple DOCTYPE declarations then it's not actually an XML file.

Comment: @MichaelKay thats exactly my problem, since its not true xml I cannot parse it the same way you'd parse xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting a file into multiple parts could be done with [`csplit(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/csplit.1.html), which is the utility for the task.

Either at the XML declaration `<?xml ...`

```
csplit -z --prefix output_file --suffix-format '%02d.xml' your_large.xml '/^<[?]xml[ ]/' {*}
```

or, if that does not repeat, at the `<!DOCTYPE`

```
csplit -z --prefix output_file --suffix-format '%02d.xml' your_large.xml '/<!DOCTYPE/' {*}
```

which will result in `output_file00.xml`, `output_file01.xml`, etc.

Comment: The first regex will also match an xml-stylesheet processing instruction. Not to mention a nested XML document within a CDATA section (if you have any of those, then you're pretty well hosed).

Comment: @MichaelKay You're right, I shall add a space and a start-of-line marker to the regex. The situation is messed-up anyway, and so far the OP did not show a meaningful sample of what they actually have, either.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thank you for your suggestions I went ahead and edited to file I am working with to show the multiple doctype declarations

Comment: @justinviola Now that you've updated your XML sample, use the first command in my answer.

Comment: @Tomalak I am using the command as instructed but getting an error. csplit -z --prefix file --suffix-format '%02d.xml' handSurgery.xml '/^<[?]xml[ ]/' '{*}' and the error is: csplit: illegal option -- z and I cannot seem to find a solution. Any thoughts?

Comment: @justinviola Are you using `-z` or `--z` (two dashes)? `--z` does not work.

Comment: @Tomalak I am only using 1 dash ```-z``` ```csplit -z --prefix file --suffix-format```

Comment: @justinviola Maybe your csplit version simply is too old to support this parameter? Look at what it does and decide whether you can live without it.

Comment: Here is what worked for me: ```brew install coreutils``` then simply adding a g to csplit ```gcsplit -z --prefix output_file --suffix-format '%02d.xml' handsurgery.xml '/^<[?]xml[ ]/' {*}``` I probably should have mentioned I was working on a MAC

Answer (score 1):

If your input document prolog actually contains multiple document type declarations (multiple DOCTYPEs), or doesn't appear to have a document element, then it might very well be full SGML rather than XML. Though your example code has neither.

Comment: Since the OP's file starts with an XML declaration, chances are high that it was meant to be XML.

Comment: @Tomalak True, but then the example code doesn't fit the question in the first place